# Inverse of a binary matrix in C

Tags: c, algorithm, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse, binary-matrix

I have a binary matrix (zeros and ones) `D[][]` of dimension nxn where n is large (approximately around 1500 - 2000). I want to find the inverse of this matrix in C.

Since I'm new to C, I started with a 3 x 3 matrix and working around to generalize it to N x N. This works for int values, however since I'm working with binary `1`'s and `0`'s. In this implementation, I need `unsigned int` values.

I could find many solutions for `int` values but I didn't come across any solution for `unsigned int`. I'd like to find the inverse of a N x N binary matrix without using any external libraries like blas/lapack. It'd be great if anyone could provide a lead on M x N matrix.

Please note that I need inverse of a matrix, not the pseudo-inverse.

```
/* To find the inverse of a matrix using LU decomposition */

/* standard Headers */
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    /* Variable declarations */
    int i,j;
    unsigned int n,m;
    unsigned int rows,cols;
    unsigned int D[3][3], d[3], C[3][3];
    unsigned int x, s[3][3];
    unsigned int y[3];
    void LU();    
    n = 2;
    rows=3;cols=3;

    /* the matrix to be inverted */

    D[0][0] = 1;
    D[0][1] = 1;
    D[0][2] = 0;
    D[1][0] = 0;
    D[1][1] = 1;
    D[1][2] = 0;
    D[2][0] = 1;
    D[2][1] = 1;
    D[2][2] = 1;

    /* Store the matrix value for camparison later.
     this is just to check the results, we don't need this
     array for the program to work */
    for (m = 0; m <= rows-1; m++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= cols-1; j++) {
            C[m][j] = D[m][j];
        }
    }

    /* Call a sub-function to calculate the LU decomposed matrix. Note that
     we pass the two dimensional array [D] to the function and get it back */
    LU(D, n);

    printf(" \n");
    printf("The matrix LU decomposed \n");
    for (m = 0; m <= rows-1; m++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= cols-1; j++){
        printf(" %d \t", D[m][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    /*  TO FIND THE INVERSE */

    /* to find the inverse we solve [D][y]=[d] with only one element in
     the [d] array put equal to one at a time */

    for (m = 0; m <= rows-1; m++) {
        d[0] = 0;
        d[1] = 0;
        d[2] = 0;
        d[m] = 1;
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            x = 0;
            for (j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++){
                x = x + D[i][j] * y[j];
            }
            y[i] = (d[i] - x);
        }

        for (i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
            x = 0;
            for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
                x = x + D[i][j] * s[j][m];
            }
            s[i][m] = (y[i] - x) / D[i][i];
        }
    }

    /* Print the inverse matrix */
    printf("The Inverse Matrix\n");
    for (m = 0; m <= rows-1; m++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= cols-1; j++){
            printf(" %d \t", s[m][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    /* check that  the product of the matrix with its iverse results
     is  indeed a unit matrix  */
    printf("The product\n");
    for (m = 0; m <= rows-1; m++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= cols-1; j++){
            x = 0;
            for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
                x = x + C[m][i] * s[i][j];
            }
            //printf(" %d    %d    %f \n", m, j, x);
            printf("%d \t",x);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

/* The function that calcualtes the LU deomposed matrix.
 Note that it receives the matrix as a two dimensional array
 of pointers. Any change made to [D] here will also change its
 value in the main function. So there is no need of an explicit
 "return" statement and the function is of type "void". */

void LU(int (*D)[3][3], int n) {
    int i, j, k;
    int x;
    printf("The matrix \n");
    for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
        printf(" %d  %d  %d \n", (*D)[j][0], (*D)[j][1], (*D)[j][2]);
    }
    for (k = 0; k <= n - 1; k++) {
        for (j = k + 1; j <= n; j++) {
            x = (*D)[j][k] / (*D)[k][k];
            for (i = k; i <= n; i++) {
                (*D)[j][i] = (*D)[j][i] - x * (*D)[k][i];
            }
            (*D)[j][k] = x;
        }
    }

}
```

This is just a sample example that I tried and I have -1 values in the inverse matrix which is my main concern. I have 1000 x 1000 matrix of binary values and the inverse should also be in binary.

The matrix:

```
 1  1  0 
 0  1  0 
 1  1  1
```

The matrix LU decomposed:

```
 1   1   0  
 0   1   0  
 1   0   1
```

The Inverse Matrix:

```
 1  -1   0  
 0   1   0  
-1   0   1
```

The product:

```
 1   0   0  
 0   1   0  
 0   0   1
```

Comment: Why do you think you need unsigned ints for 1 and 0? They are perfectly representable in signed ints, too.

Comment: That's fine. But my requirement is that I need the inverse matrix in 1's and 0's , not negative values.

Comment: What do you mean by "inverse matrix"? Is it the commonly known one (having A, find B to make AB=I)?

Comment: As a quick sanity check, are you certain that your Boolean matrix actually has an inverse? Your example does not - the only square Boolean matrices that have an inverse defined are permutation matrices, as per http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/724782.pdf. Could you also define what you mean by inverse in this context?

Comment: why do you think that for every matrix containing only 0s and 1s the inverse   matrix also contains only 0s and 1s?

Comment: Also the inverse matrix is unique. If you found one thats the only one. You cant just look for another one which contains no negative numbers since there is only one. But it depends what field you are using. Maybe you are using F2?

Comment: A binary matrix would rather be one that stores values in bits, not in `int`. And why are you using array pointers as parameter, `int (*D)[3][3]` instead of an array (that will decay into an array pointer), `int D[3][3]`. It would make the code far less painful to read.

Comment: Perhaps there is some misunderstanding. If the underlying field is indeed `F2`, `-1` and `1` are the same.

Comment: But if the field is F2 his calculations are wrong.

Comment: @ACascarino I had a quick look into the paper and that's what I require :) I am actually working with non-square matrices but since I couldn't find any solution to inverse a non-square matrix I tried to multiply my non-square matrix with it's transpose to convert it to square matrix and then work on it. I have a 84 x 104 binary matrix whose inverse exists. Could you please help me find a way to find the inverse of my non-square matrix (where no. of rows < no. of cols) . By Inverse, I mean AB = I (where A:matrix, B:Inverse of A, I:Identity matrix)

Comment: @Stan Yes I mean AB = I, where B contains only binary values.

Comment: Beware, if you only want binary values, what are the rules for addition? Is is integer addition (1 + 1 = 2, 1 + (-1) = 0) or logical one ( 1 + 1 = 1 )?

Comment: BTW: `m < rows;` is clearer, potentially faster, and more idiomatic than than `m <= rows-1;` and better for the pathological case of `row == 0`.

Comment: Using `printf(" %d \t", s[m][j]);` to print an `unsigned` outside the `int` range is UB.  Recommend to use `signed int D[3][3] ...`

Comment: **Solved** : I was able to do binary inverse of my matrix using _Gaussian elimination method_ where we perform modulo 2 addition of 2 rows and swap 2 rows based on the conditions given in the Gaussian elimination method. Thanks all for your support.